# Parse a Protocol paragraph with matcher?

Tags: java, regex, string

I try to write a Server-Client program. I can send protocol text and get text correctly.
But when I try to parse text, I got problem with Matcher Class. Because it matches only first line. So how can I find right String and parse text. I think Matcher don't try to match other line .if it is bug how can I fix it or I am going to split each line and then try to parse.

An example is below, I can't match String on expression.

```
String veri ="SIP/2.0 200 OK\r\n"
+"Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.10.10.34:5060;branch=z9hG4bK3834f681a;received=10.10.10.17\r\n"
+"From: <sip:4420145@10.10.10.24>;tag=as153459088\r\n"
+"To: <sip:44520145@10.10.10.24>;tag=as6163450a5a\r\n"
+"Call-ID: 1e0ssdfdb7f456e5977bc0df60645348cf1ce@[::1]\r\n"
+"CSeq: 18368 REGISTER\r\n"
+"Server: Asterisk PBX 11.3.0\r\n"
+"Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH\r\n"
+"Supported: replaces, timer\r\n"
+"Expires: 120\r\n"
+"Contact: <sip:345dgd@10.10.10.17:5060>;expires=120\r\n"
+"Date: Sat, 29 Jun 2013 14:00:50 GMT\r\n"
+"Content-Length: 0";
  //veri="To: <sip:3453@10.10.10.24>;tag=34dgd\r\n";
  Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^To\\: (.*);tag=(.*)$");

  Matcher m = p1.matcher(veri);

  if(m.find()){

    System.out.println(m.group(1).trim());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enable *Multiline mode* of matching using `(?m)` embedded flag or [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) mode in your regex. This way, the `$` will stop at every line-terminator, instead of the end of entire input.

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(?m)^To: (.*);tag=(.*)$");
```

Also, instead of:

```
if(m.find())
```

you should use:

```
while (m.find())
```

Also note that you are mismatching the *Matcher* reference name. You are using *matcher* inside your `if`, but you defined *m*.

P.S: You are re-assigning a new value to your string at the end. Make sure, you use `+=` instead of `=`.

Comment: First of all , thanks for reply. when i compile i can't get right sentences. it still dont try to match other lines. İ try to leanr where i am wrong on here http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html . but  cant find.

Comment: @Acablack. Sorry, edited the answer. Missed the `(?m)` flag. Now it would work.

Comment: oww yeah it is for test why it cant match other lines. Thanks for Ps . And yes it is working with (m) flag. But i wonder something. When i put a breakpoint on println and view m.find() it says false. why it turns false after reading true. it is weird.

Comment: @Acablack. I made one more edit. The last quantifier I forgot to make reluctant. Now it will give you both the matches.

Comment: @Acablack. Breakpoint gives you false, because there is only one line matching that regex. So, it will give `true` only once.

Comment: i think this reguler expression is a art . hard to desing. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlanMoore. Yeah right. I messed it. First I made it `(?s)` flag instead of `(?m)`. Forgot to remove `(?s)`, and then used reluctant quantifier. Funny things happens :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex

```
^To:\s+([^;]*);tag=(\w+)
```